# Find IPs From Ranges In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip

I am trying to fetch the ips from the ranges (172.16.3.20 to 192.168.1.1) using the following code but it is taking lot of time and cpu and sometimes it doesnt work at all. Is there any better way of finding it? Output required is as follows:
172.16.3.21
172.16.3.22
...
...
192.167.255.255
192.168.1.1

Code:

```
start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))  
end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))   
ip_range = []  
temp = start  
ip_range.append(start_ip)  
while temp != end:    
    start[3] += 1  
    for i in (3, 2, 1):
       if temp[i] == 256:
          temp[i] = 0
          temp[i-1] += 1
    ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, temp)))
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes. thanks @ MrNobody33

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
from ipaddress import IPv4Address

start = IPv4Address('172.16.3.20') + 1
end = IPv4Address('192.168.1.1')
ips = []
while start <= end:
    ips.append(start)
    start += 1
```

Comment: it worked as per your suggestions